# calloc returns success when malloc fails

Tags: malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

Is there a scenario where `malloc` fails, while `calloc` returns success. Suppose i give `malloc(20)` and `calloc(4*5)`, does there exist any scenario where `malloc` could fail and `calloc` succeeds. If so what is the exact reason for this.

Comment: Not that I can think of. Is this actually happening?

Comment: @Marcelo. Yes there is a scenario. But i could not find the reason for this

Comment: I can only imagine the opposite: `malloc()` succeeding and `calloc()` failing with a SIGKILL to the current program due to _overcommitting_ (`man 3 malloc` _BUGS_ section) resulting in OOM to kill the program.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of where `malloc()` fails and `calloc()` succeeds is if some library (or your application) overrides one and not the other.

Certainly any `libc` where this would happen is broken.

Comment: Is this possible. I am not sure. During malloc(20), the system cannot find 20 contiguous bytes and so it fails. But calloc(4*5) can find 4 five byte locations and so calloc succeeds ??

Comment: calloc(4, 5) does not allocate 4 separate chunks of memory; it only has one return value, and the returned pointer points at a buffer that can hold 4 elements of 5 bytes each, i.e. a single contiguous buffer containing at least 20 bytes.